# No such module 'Alamofire' When Importing the Alamofire Module To My Project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, podfile

I'm new to IOS it's my first project, I want to use Alamofire library in my project I followed all the steps to install the library using Cocoapods and everything should be working normally, but I'm getting this error "No such module 'Alamofire'" when I want to import the library module to my project [this is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhHuo.png)

[this the pod configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8L67.png)

[This is the Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwV8S.png)

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: From your picture, there is no Pods project. Are you opening the project via the `.xcworkspace` file cocoapods created? That's what you should use

Comment: You need to open FFMSSP.xcworkspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the project from workSpace (.`xcworkspace`) not from `xcodeproj` file after you successfully install the pods from terminal